# Selenium WebDriver in Ruby: Preventing the test from closing the browser window at end

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rubymine

I appear to be having the exact *opposite* problem many other people have - in that my Selenium tests in Ruby will close the browser window at test end, no matter what the end result is. Pass or fail, it will always close the browser. I would like to stop this.

Context:

Previously I coded tests in Java using IntelliJ IDEA. Browser windows for Selenium tests in this case would NOT close at all period unless you used driver.quit(). This is actually quite useful as it means that the browser window would stay open if the test failed - which meant I could look at where it stopped in the browser and help figure out why it failed. This was also useful for test *writing* as it meant that I could essentially pick up where I left off to write the next block instead of having to keep a parallel tab going in another browser by hand to get the next set of selectors in the given screen.

I've found in Ruby using RubyMine that the browser will close when the test ends in any capacity. This is a bit of a problem. While technically I could take a screencap on failure, it'd mean that I'd have a harder time retracing why it failed (back button on browser, typing in fields to work out if a quirk in our UI caused it, etc). And of course, screencaps take up hard drive space. ;)

I've tried the detach=true (and True) command switch for Chrome and that has not worked.

Setup:

- IDE: RubyMine
- Gems: selenium-webdriver
- Browser: Chrome, using ChromeDriver. (In Ruby this just involves using WebDriver)
- OS: OSX

Not headless, using no other frameworks/testing environments. It is quite literally a few lines of setup and then hitting the run button in RubyMine in a bog-standard .rb.

Summary:

I haven't been able to find any existing questions here or in other places online for Ruby specifically for keeping a Selenium test in RubyMine from closing the window on test end. "Test end" in this case refers to success (reaching the end of the .rb) or failure (Tracebacks, in this case). I would prefer that the window would stay open until it'd hit a driver.quit line. Is there any way I can set this up?

Thank you very much. I hope this isn't redundant. I also hope this will help other testers in the future :)

Comment: I hope you figure out a good solution. If you need an immediate workaround you can call `loop { sleep 1 }` to prevent the program from ending.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Interesting issue to solve, but it feels like you are trading one set of problems for another IMHO.

Comment: @orde his questions are pretty clear. He can't be more clearer than this.

Comment: OK...so post an answer :)

Comment: Yes, I am going to post an answer.

Comment: @rvanderclute I posted the question here in WATIR(which is a wrapper for ruby selenium binding). I have had the solution for this problem but it's not working now. Please see my question here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926616/chrome-detach-option-is-no-longer-working`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:desired_capabilities` to set this flag:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("goog:chromeOptions" => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Note that old examples will be using "chromeOptions", but for newer Chrome versions, it will need to be "goog:chromeOptions".

Comment: hmmm, this one is not working for me either. See above example code, now that I have even the vaguest idea to show.

Comment: But thank you very much for posting an answer :D I did not anticipate getting any responses, and have been quite busy!

Comment: @rvanderclute, the code you listed is different. It has "goog:chrome_options" where it needs to be "goog:chromeOptions". Can you try again?

Comment: hahahahahahaha that worked!! thank you so much :D I tend to get crosseyed sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

@JustinKo has posted an answer here

[Chrome detach option is no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926616/chrome-detach-option-is-no-longer-working/58935849#58935849)

You can pass Chrome Options using the following format:

```
    browser = Watir::Browser.new(
      :chrome,
      'goog:chromeOptions' => {detach: true}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Justin Ko worked for me. However at the time of posting I am getting a warning telling me to use

```
capabilities: caps
```

instead of

```
desired_capabilities: caps
```

as it is now currently deprecated at the time of posting.

I do not have enough reputation to be able to comment so I am posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

require 'selenium-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path="C:/webdriver/chromedriver.exe"
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("goog:chromeOptions" => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: caps

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted. Edit and indent the code so that it can be read and understood easily.