# Chrome detach option is no longer working

Tags: ruby, watir

There is a question for Ruby Selenium Binding here

[Selenium WebDriver in Ruby: Preventing the test from closing the browser window at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920198/selenium-webdriver-in-ruby-preventing-the-test-from-closing-the-browser-window)

He was trying to not to close the window of Chrome after the execution but it's not working. I have had the solution for this problem, the given below program works fine earlier, but now it's not working

```
require 'watir'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: {detach: true})
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
b.goto('www.google.co.uk')
```

When I execute this program, this program is giving the warning of

```
2019-11-19 09:33:37 WARN Watir ["use_capabilities"] You can pass values directly into Watir::Browser opt without needing to use :desired_capabilities
```

But I don't know how to use this `Watir::Browser opt`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Chrome Options using the following format:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :chrome,
  'goog:chromeOptions' => {detach: true}
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Gave the reference to this answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920198/selenium-webdriver-in-ruby-preventing-the-test-from-closing-the-browser-window/58946043#58946043

Comment: @Rajagopalan, wouldn't that question need an answer that is translated to pure Selenium-WebDriver?

Comment: Watir is implementing this `  selenium_args = Capabilities.new(browser, *args).to_args` to achieve but I don't know how to bring it in selenium directly. Perhaps, If you write an answer there, it would be good.